# Check if any property in a object is empty

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following function in a class:

```php
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api_url = env('SUPRE_API');
        $this->token = env('SUPRE_TOKEN');
        if($this->api_url == null || $this->token == null){
            throw new \Exception("Could not gather the Token or URL from the .env file. Are you sure it has been set?");
        }
    }
```

However I would like to check if any property in the $this object is empty in a dynamic way, without using an If, considering this will have more properties later.

Comment: in a loop you can get the values. foreach($this as $key => $val)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [iterate over `$this`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) and throw your exception on first empty property found:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->api_url = env('SUPRE_API');
    $this->token = env('SUPRE_TOKEN');

    foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == null) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find {$key} value. Are you sure it has been set?");
        }
    }
}
```